# If a thread or AsyncTask is started by an Activity, will the thread or AsyncTask be killed if the Activity is destroyed?

Tags: android-activity

If a thread or AsyncTask is started by an Activity, will the thread or AsyncTask be killed as well when the Activity is destroyed?

Comment: they are not killed if activity is destroyed. however they are killed when app is stopped

Comment: Is this conclusive?  I read somewhere that this behavior is unpredictable.